# How to convert string in a file to an int in Python?

Tags: python, io

I have a file that has only numbers on each line. My question is, how do I convert each line from a string to an int?

I know i can do int(str) but how do I do this over each line of the file? I want to sum each number on each line and also count how many lines there are.

Ex of file contents:

```
> 5  
> 3  
> 5  
> 90
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample file of how it looks.

Comment: @Alderven that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could answer this by googling, but try breaking this into steps:

Open the file:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    <do something with the file>
```

Read the lines out:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Iterate through the lines:

```
with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        <do something with the lines>
```

Add them up and print it out:

```
total = 0

with open("file.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        total += int(line)

print("total is ", total)
```

Comment: Could have been achieved with significantly less code (see my answer below).

Comment: @GavinWong I think if someone is only just learning how to read a file and convert a type then list comprehension might be a bit far.

Comment: @GavinWong and both solutions are 6 lines excluding whitespace :)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [int(x.strip()) for x in content]
```

This reads every line in the file, converts the values into integers, and appends them all into a list called `content`.

To sum all the values just do:

```
sum = 0
for value in content:
    sum += content
```